# Plot to represent coverage of a sequence

Tags: python, plot, graph, representation

Does anyone have an idea of generating a plot that would look something like this: [image: plot]

Basically, I would have sequences, say T1 and T2, which need to be aligned to the "main" sequence. Also, please note that there is no need for actual alignment here, the sequence range is already known (For eg. T1 is 7-12, 32-36). These regions simply needs to be place accordingly and represented.

I thought of representing it in a bar plot, but as there would be breaks in the region it wouldnt be helpful.

Comment: Why not simply switch to a monospace font and write the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very minimalistic example that should get you going:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Main = "123684651984656497243684986425465798"
T1 = "651984"
T2 = "864"


f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.text(.1,.5, 
        "\n".join(
            [Main, 
             " "*Main.index(T1) + T1, 
             " "*Main.index(T2) + T2]),
        ha="left", 
        va="center",
        family="monospace")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please note that there are two regions in T1 itself. How can that be represented?

Comment: well... I'm not gonna do all of it... it's just to show you how it can be done quick and easy. (you just need to calculate the number of spaces you need to append for the second sequence)

Comment: Ahh okay. Thank you